# Jinja2 - copy variable instead of referencing it

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to be able to copy a variable in Jinja2 (`2.10`) instead of just referencing it, but couldn't find a way to do it.

See the following example:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.ext import do
env = Environment(extensions=[do])
template = env.from_string('''
  {%- set base = {"elems": {"a": "aa"}} -%}
  {%- set data = {"elems": base.elems} -%}
  {%- do data.elems.update({"a": "bb"}) -%}
  {{ base.elems.a }} - "aa" expected
  {{ data.elems.a }} - "bb" expected
''')
template.render()
```

The result is: `'bb - "aa" expected\nbb - "bb" expected'`

So this means that `data.elems` is not a copy of `base.elems`, but a reference to it instead.
I need to have a copy of `base.elems` in `data.elems` instead.

I tried:

- `base.get('elems')`
- `base|attr('elems')`

But none of those worked. Is there any way to copy values in Jinja2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ python q54718238.py
aa - "aa" expected
  bb - "bb" expected
```

The trick is knowing that a lot of Python's data types are by reference. So, calling `copy()` on the object fixes it. Note that I changed `{%- set data = {"elems": base.elems} -%}` to `{%- set data = {"elems": base.elems.copy()} -%}`.

```py
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.ext import do
env = Environment(extensions=[do])
template = env.from_string('''
  {%- set base = {"elems": {"a": "aa"}} -%}
  {%- set data = {"elems": base.elems.copy()} -%}
  {%- do data.elems.update({"a": "bb"}) -%}
  {{ base.elems.a }} - "aa" expected
  {{ data.elems.a }} - "bb" expected
''')
print(template.render())
```

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't know I could use `.copy()` on Jinja2 objects.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me when I tried to copy the whole dictionary.
I ended up getting the copy by doing the following:

`{% set newdict = olddict | to_json | from_json %}`

Note: in my case I am using Jinja2 with Ansible and not python directly